# I can't connect to home wifi from phone D-Link Modem

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a `Dlink 2790U` Modem with Firmware Version ME_1.00, and for some reason I am not able to connect to my wifi from any phone ! It works fine from any computer but when I try to connect from a phone it give me `Wrong password` or `Couldn't connect try again` message, and I am only able to connect after retrying many many times ( If I am lucky)

I can't figure out what is the problem, I checked Mac adress filtering and any other type of filtering and they are all disabled, I checked Max Clients parameter and it's set to 16( which is more then enough)

I double checked the password, changed it many times but nothing seems to work

Comment: What model router and what kind of phones (android? IOS? All one brand?). What channel is WiFI on and what are its settings? (Also, what standard and how wide are your channels?)

Comment: Modem Dsl2790u, Android phones, different brands different versions , Channel set to auto , 802.11 Mode is b/g/n band width 20M/40M basically everything set to default like I always configure my modems

Comment: That is a really low spec device - my guess is its got old firmware compatibility is therefor iffy!  (it doesn't seem to support any current gen standards (no usb3, no VDSL, **no 8011ac**). I would see if locking it to 20 MHz channels helps - I had an issue with this on some older gear). I would also play arroubd with the channel - try locking it to 1 or 6 as not all devices support higher channels due to regional license issues. Also see if disabling encryption or changing encryption standard helps.